# onChange or other option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get **rid of the save buttons** on my websites.

I know the most obvious way would be to do a **jQuery `onChange` event**. But it seems like it's going to be a **lot of queries on the server**.

I also thought about doing `onBlur`, but that would mean the user needs to click somewhere else before loading a new page, and if he forgets, the changes will be lost.

Is there any other more efficient way?

For example, what does Asana use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use debouncing, so that you only make your AJAX call after a brief period of inactivity. Here is the Underscore.js implementation: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce